# Binary tree implemented by c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

Node *search(Node *root, int x) {

    Node *p = root;

    while (p != NULL) {

        if (p->key == x) {
            return p;
        }

        else if (p->key < x) {
            p = p->right;
        }

        else {
            p = p->left;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

Node *insert(Node *root, int x) {

    Node *p = root;

    Node *parent = NULL;

    while (p != NULL) {

        parent = p;

        if (p->key == x) {
            printf("same key.\n");
            return p;
        }

        else if (p->key < x) {
            p = p->right;
        }

        else {
            p = p->left;
        }
    }

    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->key = x;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    if (parent != NULL) {
        if (parent->key < newNode->key) {
            parent->right = newNode;
        }
        else {
            parent->left = newNode;
        }
    }
    return newNode;
}

Node *delete(Node *root, int x) {
    Node *p = root;
    Node *parent = NULL;

    while ((p != NULL) && (p->key != x)) {
        
        parent = p;
        
        if (p->key < x) {
            p = p->right;
        }

        else {
            p = p->left;
        }
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("No Node you want.\n");
        return root;
    }

    if (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL) {

        if (parent == NULL) {
            root = NULL;
        }
        
        else {
            if (parent->left == p) {
                parent->left = NULL;
            }

            else {
                parent->right = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    else if (p->left == NULL || p->right == NULL) {

        Node *child = (p->left != NULL) ? p->left : p->right;

        if (parent == NULL) {
            root = child;
        }
        else {
            if (parent->left == p) {
                parent->left = child;
            }
            else {
                parent->right = child;
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        Node *succeccor_parent = p;
        Node *succeccor = p->left;
        while (succeccor->right != NULL) {
            succeccor_parent = succeccor;
            succeccor = succeccor->right;
        }
        p->key = succeccor->key;
        if (succeccor_parent->right == succeccor) {
            succeccor_parent->right = succeccor_parent->left;
        }
        else {
            succeccor_parent->left = succeccor_parent->left;
        }
        p = succeccor;
    }
    free(p);
}

void display(Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n", root->key);
    display(root->left);
    display(root->right);
}

int main() {

    // FILE *ip = fopen("C:\\VScode\\final\\input.txt", "r");

    Node *root = insert(NULL, 5);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 18);
    insert(root, 1);
    insert(root, 3);
    insert(root, 8);
    insert(root, 6);
    insert(root, 11);
    insert(root, 7);

    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

---

this is my code.

and Result Value is

```
5
2
1
3
18
8
6
7
11
```

But I want something else.

```
5 2
5 18
2 1
2 3
18 8
8 6
8 11
6 7
```

I want Parents node and children node show together.
I know I need to revise display function something, but I don't know exactly how.

and this is different question.
"FILE *ip = fopen(“C:\VScode\final\input.txt”, “r”);"

The file I made in advance "input.txt", and I want to pass the value to the insertion function.
How can I do?

I'd really appreciate it if you'd give me a advice.

Comment: Ask one question per post. Asking about using `FILE` and `fopen` should be separate from asking about displaying the tree.

Comment: Basically, edit your question to only have one of the questions, and edit the title to make clear which question is being asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output you want by changing `display` to print lines showing the key of the current node and its children:

```
void display(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    if (root->left)
        printf("%d %d\n", root->key, root->left->key);
    if (root->right)
        printf("%d %d\n", root->key, root->right->key);
    display(root->left);
    display(root->right);
}
```

Comment: I just realized that there was a reply.
Thank you for helping me.
Thanks to you, I was able to solve it.